# How to reset PeriodicSync

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contentresolver

is there any way to reset the period of a PeriodicSync??

I mean, if the period is 10 mins, 7 mins have passed since the last sync, reset the period so next sync would by within 10 mins again, not 3.

ContentResolver has no methods for this. I've tried to:

- Invoke ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync() over an existing PeriodicSync. As stated in the javadocs the period gets updated, but not resetted.
- Stop and start the PeriodicSync. In this case the sync gets triggered when restarting, what I don't want to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem and not found way to update settings only:

```
ContentResolver.removePeriodicSync
```

and

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync
```

change settings and as You write it runs sync